# How do i compare each row of a timeseries against a constant in R

Tags: r

i am trying to achieve something simple but i did not find an elegant way yet.

I want to compare each element of a timeseries of interest rates against a cap and a floor.

I currently use:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("TB3MS", src = "FRED")
index <- TB3MS["1970-01-01::1999-12-01"] ; plot(index)
margin <- 0.02
crate <- index/100 + margin # composite rate (index + margin)

plot(crate)


floor <- 0.06
cap <- 0.12

for (i in 1:length(crate)){
  crate[i,1] <- min(crate[i,1],cap)
}

for (i in 1:length(crate)){
  crate[i,1] <- max(crate[i,1],floor)
}

plot(crate)
```

but this must be possible to do in a more elegant way.

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `pmax` and `pmin` or with base R

```
crate$TB3MS <- pmax(crate$TB3MS, floor)
crate$TB3MS <- pmin(crate$TB3MS, cap)

crate$TB3MS[ crate$TB3MS<floor ] <- floor
crate$TB3MS[ crate$TB3MS>cap ] <- cap
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am new to R and this help a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmin` and `pmax` function to avoid the loops

```
crate[,1] <- pmin(crate[,1],cap)
crate[,1] <- pmax(crate[,1],floor)
```